# Sveltekit Static Asset import ...css?url failure

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

sveltekit (vite) is assuming on a css file that is JS and trowing errors on trying to preprocess the file

I have a basic sveltekit v1.16.3 project with a css file like this

```css
.mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container {
    padding-bottom: calc(100% / 1);
}
```

i have a svelte Component like this with [Explicit URL Imports](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#explicit-url-imports)

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import testCSS from './test.css?url'
    console.log(testCSS)
</script>
<svelte:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{testCSS}">
</svelte:head>
```

when i run i am getting this error

```
/src/routes/test.css
Internal server error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. You may need to install appropriate plugins to handle the .css?url=&inline= file format, or if it's an asset, add "**/*.css?url=&inline=" to `assetsInclude` in your configuration.
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: /home/projects/parilmppm.github/src/routes/test.css?url=&inline=:2:36
  1  |  .mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container {
  2  |      padding-bottom: calc(100% / 1);
     |                                     ^
  3  |  }
```

why dose vite preprocess the css at all?
why is it trying to process the css as js?

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/github/isaacwein/test-import-url-error?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't just import as `import './test.css';`?

Comment: yes, because I have 2 CSS files one for dark mode and one for light mode like this [Building Your Theme](https://sveltematerialui.com/THEMING.md#:~:text=the%20theme%20variables.-,Building%20Your%20Theme,-In%20your%20package)  i have a condition to change the css file and the condition is on the link element

Comment: from my understanding its sounds like a bug from Sveltekit side thay are adding this inline query to the url that what it make it crash